# maximum recursion depth exceeded (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'PatientID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'99' : ['1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],'75' : ['0','0','1','0','0','1','1','0'],'C604' : ['1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],'C602' : ['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],'C601' : ['1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0'],'C603' : ['0','0','1','1','1','0','1','0'],'C605' : ['0','1','1','0','0','0','1','0'],'C606' : ['0','1','1','1','1','0','1','0'],'44' : ['1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],'L239' : ['0','0','1','1','1','0','1','0'], '32' : ['1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],}).set_index('PatientID')
```

When I try to add columns by doing

```
df.eval('(`99`+`75`)')
```

I am getting this error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Trying to understand what this means and how I can solve this

Comment: The shown code does not reproduce this error in `pandas 1.3.3`

Comment: you can try the parameter `engine='python'` in the eval

Comment: If I add engine = 'python' this error deosnt pop up but then its beating the eval function. for example 1 + 0 is becoming 10 while I'd like to see 1 + 0 = 1 .

Comment: I am on pandas 1.3.3

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error from the code above, Python 3.9.7, Pandas 1.3.2 via Anaconda on macOS.

Comment: Seems the numexpr engine has issues with object and string dtypes, see e.g. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34044#issuecomment-645202365. Could you use int dtypes for your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe easiest to change the datatype to int and then sum the columns '99' and '75' with the eval. If you really want to use that eval() function.

```
df = df.astype('int32')

df['new_column'] = df.eval('(`99`+`75`)')
```

Without eval() it is simply:

```
df['new'] = df['99'] + df['75']
```